# how can I get data from RecyclerAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

I have RecyclerView and RecyclerAdapter with two `ArrayList<String>ingridientsfinal` and `ArrayList<String> dependingridients` ArrayLists and one Switch `mySwitch`.

Adapter below.

```
public class recyclerAdapterIngridients extends RecyclerView.Adapter<recyclerAdapterIngridients.myViewHolder>{
    Context context;
    int intege;
    String[] glux;
    public static ArrayList<String> ingridientsfinal;
    public static ArrayList<String> dependingridients;


    public static class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        @SuppressLint("UseSwitchCompatOrMaterialCode")
        Switch mySwitch;
        TextView ingridtitle, avel;

        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ingridtitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingridientTemple);
            mySwitch=itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            avel=itemView.findViewById(R.id.depend);
            mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(!mySwitch.isChecked()){
                        mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                        for (int i=0; i<dependingridients.size(); i++){
                            if(getAdapterPosition()==i) {
                                String h = orderPlain.priceView.getText().toString();
                                h=h.replace(h.substring(h.length()-1), "");
                                String L = avel.getText().toString();
                                L=L.replace(L.substring(L.length()-1), "");
                                orderPlain.priceView.setText(Integer.parseInt(h)
                                        -Integer.parseInt(L)+"$");
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        mySwitch.setChecked(true);
                        for (int i=0; i<dependingridients.size(); i++){
                            if(getAdapterPosition()==i) {
                                String h = orderPlain.priceView.getText().toString();
                                h=h.replace(h.substring(h.length()-1), "");
                                String L = avel.getText().toString();
                                L=L.replace(L.substring(L.length()-1), "");
                                orderPlain.priceView.setText(Integer.parseInt(h)
                                        +Integer.parseInt(L)+"$");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public recyclerAdapterIngridients(ArrayList<String> list, Context c, @Nullable String[] list2){
        context=c;
        ingridientsfinal=list;
        if(list2!=null) {
            glux = list2;
            dependingridients = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(list2));
        }else{
            glux=null;
            dependingridients = new ArrayList<>(0);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.temple, parent, false );
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if(glux!=null){
                    try {
                        if(position==dependingridients.size())
                            holder.mySwitch.setEnabled(false);
                        String a = ingridientsfinal.get(position-dependingridients.size());
                        holder.ingridtitle.setText(a);
                    }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
                try {
                    String b =  dependingridients.get(position);
                    holder.ingridtitle.setText(b);
                    holder.mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                    String g = b.replace(b,"1$");
                    holder.avel.setText(g);
                }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ignored){}
            }else {
                    if(position==0)
                        holder.mySwitch.setEnabled(false);
                    String a = ingridientsfinal.get(position);
                    holder.ingridtitle.setText(a);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(dependingridients!=null) {
            return dependingridients.size() + ingridientsfinal.size();
        }else {
            return ingridientsfinal.size();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

**I want to get positions of switches that are switched from another class. Can someone suggest how can i do that? thanks)**

Comment: This solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514968/how-to-display-total-checkbox-checked-in-a-recyclerview/65515033#65515033

Comment: Check out this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119745/9701793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Interface to have a `communication` between Adapter and `Activity/Fragment`

In your adapter:

```
public interface onclickListener{
   void onClick();
}
```

Then create a variable of it in your adapter class and pass through `constructor` to `adapter class` and use it in `Activity/Fragment`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solving. I just created new `public static ArrayList<String> finall = new ArrayList<>();` And then I just got the position and add the value of TextView to my ArrayList. And then I just can get that ArrayList from another class.

```
public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ingridtitle=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingridientTemple);
        mySwitch=itemView.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        avel=itemView.findViewById(R.id.depend);
        mySwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(!mySwitch.isChecked()){
                    mySwitch.setChecked(false);
                    for (int i=0; i<dependingridients.size(); i++){
                        if(getAdapterPosition()==i) {
                            String h = orderPlain.priceView.getText().toString();
                            h=h.replace(h.substring(h.length()-1), "");
                            String L = avel.getText().toString();
                            L=L.replace(L.substring(L.length()-1), "");
                            orderPlain.priceView.setText(Integer.parseInt(h)
                                    -Integer.parseInt(L)+"$");
                            finall.remove(dependingridients.get(i));
                            System.out.println(finall);
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    mySwitch.setChecked(true);
                    for (int i=0; i<dependingridients.size(); i++){
                        if(getAdapterPosition()==i) {
                            String h = orderPlain.priceView.getText().toString();
                            h=h.replace(h.substring(h.length()-1), "");
                            String L = avel.getText().toString();
                            L=L.replace(L.substring(L.length()-1), "");
                            orderPlain.priceView.setText(Integer.parseInt(h)
                                    +Integer.parseInt(L)+"$");
                            String p = dependingridients.get(i);
                            System.out.println(p);
                            finall.add(p);
                            System.out.println(finall);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```