# When i delete a row from recyclerView my calculation are going wrong

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, calculation

I am making a foodbox app. I stuck at a point. The problem is that when i delete row from cart recyclerView it is miscalculating all the data of remainig items. When i open cart after closing then calculations are correctly calculated.
Now, my problem is, When i delete a row it will calculate all prices at that point. My code is below.

AdapterCalss:

```
this.context = context;
this.cartItems = cartItems;

@NonNull
@Override
public HolderCartItem onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_cart_items, parent, false);
    return new HolderCartItem(view);
}

private int itemsCount = 0;
public double allTotalPrice = 0.00;
double Price;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderCartItem holder, int position) {
    CartItemsModelClass cartItemsModelClass = cartItems.get(position);

    String id = cartItemsModelClass.getId();
    String pId = cartItemsModelClass.getpId();
    String itemName = cartItemsModelClass.getItemName();
    String price = cartItemsModelClass.getPrice();
    String finalPrice = cartItemsModelClass.getFinalPrice();
    String Items_Count = cartItemsModelClass.getItems_Count();

    holder.tvItemTitle.setText(""+itemName);
    holder.tvItemPrice.setText(""+price);
    holder.tvPriceEach.setText(""+finalPrice);
    holder.tvItemCount.setText(""+Items_Count);

    holder.tvRemoveItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EasyDB easyDB = EasyDB.init(context, "DB")
                    .setTableName("ITEMS_TABLE")
                    .addColumn(new Column("Item_Id", new String[]{"text", "unique"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("pId", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Title", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Items_Count", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Final_Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .doneTableColumn();

            easyDB.deleteRow(1, id);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item Removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            cartItems.remove(position);
            notifyItemChanged(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.d("id", ""+id);

            double grandTotal = Double.parseDouble((((MainActivity)context).tvGrandTotal.getText().toString().trim().replace("Pkr", "")));
            double totalPrice = grandTotal - Double.parseDouble(price);
            double deliveryFee = Double.parseDouble((((MainActivity)context).tvDeliveryFee.getText().toString().trim().replace("Pkr", "")));
            double subTotal = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f",totalPrice)) - Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", deliveryFee));
            ((MainActivity)context).tvSubTotal.setText("Pkr" + String.format("%.2f", subTotal));
            ((MainActivity)context).tvGrandTotal.setText("Pkr" + String.format("%.2f", Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.2f", totalPrice))));


        }
    });

    holder.ibAddItemCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            itemsCount = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvItemCount.getText().toString().trim());
            itemsCount++;
            Toast.makeText(context, ""+itemsCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (allTotalPrice == 0.00){
                allTotalPrice = Double.parseDouble(((MainActivity)context).tvSubTotal.getText().toString().trim().replace("Pkr",""));
            }


            EasyDB easyDB = EasyDB.init(context, "DB")
                    .setTableName("ITEMS_TABLE")
                    .addColumn(new Column("Item_Id", new String[]{"text", "unique"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("pId", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Title", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Items_Count", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .addColumn(new Column("Final_Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                    .doneTableColumn();

            Cursor cursor = easyDB.getAllData();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                int Id = cursor.getInt(1);

                if (id.equals(String.valueOf(Id))){
                    boolean updated1 = easyDB.updateData(5, itemsCount).rowID(Id);

                    if (updated1){
                        double finalPrice = Double.parseDouble(price) * itemsCount;

                        boolean updated2 = easyDB.updateData(6, String.valueOf(finalPrice)).rowID(Id);
                        if (updated2){
                            holder.tvPriceEach.setText(""+finalPrice);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Price = cursor.getDouble(4);

                            allTotalPrice = allTotalPrice + Price;

                            ((MainActivity)context).tvSubTotal.setText("Pkr" + String.format("%.2f", allTotalPrice));
                            String dFee = ((MainActivity)context).tvDeliveryFee.getText().toString().trim().replace("Pkr", "");
                            ((MainActivity)context).tvGrandTotal.setText("Pkr" + (allTotalPrice + Double.parseDouble(dFee.replace("Pkr", ""))));
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            holder.tvItemCount.setText(""+itemsCount);

            itemsCount = 0;
        }
    });

    holder.ibRemoveItemCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            itemsCount = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvItemCount.getText().toString().trim());

            if (itemsCount > 1){
                itemsCount--;
                Toast.makeText(context, ""+itemsCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (allTotalPrice == 0.00){
                    allTotalPrice = Double.parseDouble(((MainActivity)context).tvSubTotal.getText().toString().trim().replace("Pkr",""));
                }


                EasyDB easyDB = EasyDB.init(context, "DB")
                        .setTableName("ITEMS_TABLE")
                        .addColumn(new Column("Item_Id", new String[]{"text", "unique"}))
                        .addColumn(new Column("pId", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                        .addColumn(new Column("Title", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                        .addColumn(new Column("Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                        .addColumn(new Column("Items_Count", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                        .addColumn(new Column("Final_Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
                        .doneTableColumn();

                Cursor cursor = easyDB.getAllData();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                    int Id = cursor.getInt(1);

                    if (id.equals(String.valueOf(Id))){
                        boolean updated1 = easyDB.updateData(5, itemsCount).rowID(Id);

                        if (updated1){
                            double finalPrice = Double.parseDouble(price) * itemsCount;

                            boolean updated2 = easyDB.updateData(6, String.valueOf(finalPrice)).rowID(Id);
                            if (updated2){
                                holder.tvPriceEach.setText(""+finalPrice);
                                Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                Price = cursor.getDouble(4);

                                allTotalPrice = allTotalPrice - Price;

                                ((MainActivity)context).tvSubTotal.setText("Pkr" + String.format("%.2f", allTotalPrice));
                                String dFee = ((MainActivity)context).tvDeliveryFee.getText().toString().trim().replace("Pkr", "");
                                ((MainActivity)context).tvGrandTotal.setText("Pkr" + (allTotalPrice + Double.parseDouble(dFee.replace("Pkr", ""))));
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                            Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                holder.tvItemCount.setText(""+itemsCount);

                itemsCount = 0;
            }
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cartItems.size();
}

class HolderCartItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView tvItemTitle, tvItemPrice, tvPriceEach, tvItemCount, tvRemoveItem;
    private ImageButton ibAddItemCart, ibRemoveItemCart;

    public HolderCartItem(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvItemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemTitle);
        tvItemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemPrice);
        tvPriceEach = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPriceEach);
        tvItemCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemCount);
        tvRemoveItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvRemoveItem);
        ibAddItemCart = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibAddItemCart);
        ibRemoveItemCart = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibRemoveItemCart);


    }
}
```

}

MainActivity:

```
private RecyclerView rvRestaurant;
private List<String> tvRestaurant = new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> ivRestaurant = new ArrayList<>();
private Toolbar toolbar;
private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private String resName, delivery = "45";

private ArrayList<CartItemsModelClass> cartItemsList;
 CartItemsAdapter cartItemsAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    rvRestaurant = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvRestaurantName);
    rvRestaurant.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    firebaseFirestore.collection("Restaurants").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                    resName = documentSnapshot.getId();
                    String imageUri = documentSnapshot.get("imageUri").toString();

                    tvRestaurant.add(resName);
                    ivRestaurant.add(imageUri);

                    rvRestaurant.setAdapter(new MainActivityAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tvRestaurant, ivRestaurant));
                }
            }
        }
    });

    deleteCartData();

}

private void deleteCartData() {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.cart_view, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.cart:

            showCartDialog();

            break;
    }
    return true;
}

public double allTotalPrice = 0.00;
public TextView tvSubTotal, tvDeliveryFee, tvGrandTotal;

private void showCartDialog() {

    cartItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.cart_dialog, null);
    TextView tvShopName;
    RecyclerView rvCartItems;
    Button btnCheckOut;

    tvShopName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvShopName);
    tvSubTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSubTotal);
    tvDeliveryFee = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDeliveryFee);
    tvGrandTotal = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvGrandTotal);
    rvCartItems = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvCartItems);
    btnCheckOut = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckOut);

    tvShopName.setText(resName);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setView(view);

    EasyDB easyDB = EasyDB.init(MainActivity.this, "DB")
            .setTableName("ITEMS_TABLE")
            .addColumn(new Column("Item_Id", new String[]{"text", "unique"}))
            .addColumn(new Column("pId", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
            .addColumn(new Column("Title", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
            .addColumn(new Column("Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
            .addColumn(new Column("Items_Count", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
            .addColumn(new Column("Final_Price", new String[]{"text", "not null"}))
            .doneTableColumn();

    Cursor res = easyDB.getAllData();
    while (res.moveToNext()){
        String id = res.getString(1);
        String pId = res.getString(2);
        String title = res.getString(3);
        String price = res.getString(4);
        String items_count = res.getString(5);
        String final_price = res.getString(6);

        allTotalPrice = allTotalPrice + Double.parseDouble(final_price);

        CartItemsModelClass cartItemsModelClass = new CartItemsModelClass(
                ""+id,
                ""+pId,
                ""+title,
                ""+final_price,
                ""+price,
                ""+items_count
        );

        cartItemsList.add(cartItemsModelClass);
    }

    cartItemsAdapter = new CartItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this, cartItemsList);

    rvCartItems.setAdapter(cartItemsAdapter);

    tvDeliveryFee.setText(delivery);
    tvSubTotal.setText("Pkr" + String.format("%.2f", allTotalPrice));
    tvGrandTotal.setText("Pkr" + (allTotalPrice + Double.parseDouble(delivery.replace("Pkr", ""))));

    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            allTotalPrice = 0.00;

        }
    });

    btnCheckOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String total = tvGrandTotal.getText().toString().trim().replace("Pkr", "");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, total, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Hi, Uzair Welcome to SO Community,
It seems on Item remove Click you are notifying the adapter for change First then you're doing your calculations. try to move  ```cartItems.remove(position);```, ```notifyItemChanged(position);``` & ```notifyDataSetChanged();``` at the end line of ```holder.tvRemoveItem``` Click Listener Function.

Comment: nothing works bro. It seems when i remove an item it picks previously added items that are added in the items screen. This is not showing those items that are added in cart.

Comment: Please review it and identify the problem.

Comment: Can you tell me what and where are you getting the **Miscalculating Values**? and why are you attaching the recyclerView adapter in a **for loop**?

Comment: Q#1 answer: In ibRemoveItemCart in adapter, when i click on remove button it deletes a row but miscalculate subTotal.

Comment: Q#2 answer: I am using for loop for getting values from firbase and let them show in recyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify adapter using **notifyDataSetChanged()** after removing item from the recycler view.
Do this:

```
 this.context = context;
 this.cartItems = cartItems;   
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: try this:                                                            this.context = context;
this.cartItems = cartItems;   notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: go for this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/51119745/14979180

Comment: Insha Allah it will help you to understand whats wrong with your way of deleting item.